# MS Access sql join 5 table with group by strange chars in columns

Tags: sql, ms-access, group-by

I have this strange problem: I am trying to get some stats with group by

This joins 5 tables, 4 tables connect to one (`T_Registo`) basically to get the description of the values on the T_Registo  tables

I believe the join table is ok, but the problem is when I add the GROUP BY  part.

The result is this strange characters in all columns except one:

[table result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RoiV0.jpg)

I have done the query with different techniques like this:

```
SELECT DateDiff("n",DataHora_inicio,DataHora_fim) AS tempo_registo, 
T_Registo.Utilizador AS Utilizador,
T_Origem_Contacto.Nome_contacto, 
T_Origem_Problema.Nome_problema,
T_Problema_PED.Nome_Problema_PED,
T_Indicador_resolucao.Resolucao_desc
FROM (((T_Registo  INNER JOIN T_Problema_PED ON T_Registo.Problema_PED_ID = 
  T_Problema_PED.Problema_PED_ID)
INNER JOIN T_Indicador_resolucao ON T_Registo.Indicador_resolvido = 
  T_Indicador_resolucao.Indicador_resolvido)
INNER JOIN T_Origem_Problema ON T_Registo.Origem_problema_ID = 
  T_Origem_Problema.Origem_problema_ID)
INNER JOIN T_Origem_Contacto ON T_Registo.Origem_contacto_ID = 
  T_Origem_Contacto.Origem_contacto_ID
GROUP BY DateDiff("n",DataHora_inicio,DataHora_fim), Utilizador, 
  Nome_contacto, Nome_problema,

Nome_Problema_PED, Resolucao_desc;
```

also tried....

```
SELECT DateDiff("n",DataHora_inicio,DataHora_fim) AS tempo_registo, 
T_Registo.Utilizador AS Utilizador,
T_Origem_Contacto.Nome_contacto, 
T_Origem_Problema.Nome_problema, 
T_Problema_PED.Nome_Problema_PED,
T_Indicador_resolucao.Resolucao_desc

from 
 T_Registo,T_Problema_PED,T_Indicador_resolucao
,T_Origem_Problema,T_Origem_Contacto

where T_Registo.Problema_PED_ID = T_Problema_PED.Problema_PED_ID and 
T_Registo.Indicador_resolvido = T_Indicador_resolucao.Indicador_resolvido

and T_Registo.Origem_problema_ID = T_Origem_Problema.Origem_problema_ID and 
T_Registo.Origem_contacto_ID = T_Origem_Contacto.Origem_contacto_ID

GROUP BY DateDiff("n",DataHora_inicio,DataHora_fim), Utilizador, 
Nome_contacto, Nome_problema,

Nome_Problema_PED, Resolucao_desc
```

But the result is the same.

I have change the order of the join and add, subtract columns but still the result is no good, even thought it appears to have some impact, for example

In the above example columns Nome_contacto appears to be the correct, but if order is change the Nome_contacto column is wrong and Utilizador is ok….

Just to add some weird element to it :-)

Can you please help? This is very strange ,I have tried everything that I could remember, even migrate to SQL Server that obviously works correctly

Comment: Would you mind formatting your question, so it is easier to read?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Why do you use `GROUP BY` if you don't use any aggregation functions?

2) Most probably your description columns are Memo/Long Text.

https://bytes.com/topic/access/answers/849295-access-getting-chinese-character-unexpectedly-why

> Causes include:
>   a) You group by a memo field in a query that has a join on an unindexed
>   field:
>   http://allenbrowne.com/bug-18.html

**Workaround**

Either of the following will work around the bug:

- Do not group by the Memo field. Instead choose First in the Total row under the memo field. This not only avoids the bug, and is much more efficient to execute, but it also allows JET to return the entire memo field instead of truncating it at 255 characters.
- Index the fields involved in the JOIN.
- Or, as you did, change the data type to (short) text. :)

Comment: Thank you André. For some reason when the db was exported from sql server, some fields where data type memo. I only had to change it to text.... and it worked

Comment: changed field to short text ... works like a charm. thx a lot